# Why does ubuntu support a2dp but windows doesn't?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

I have an **Intel Proset/Wireless Bluetooth 4.0 integrated card**,
In ubuntu it detects my bluetooth headphones (**Philips SHB4000**) and I can stream audio to them, but Windows can't, I can't find the a2dp profile, I installed the newest drivers from Intel, tried installing the broadcom driver which includes the profiles but when I select the profiles to update my headphones it gives me an error, (10)
I just cannot make them work!
I also tried this program:
http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php
But it cannot detect my integrated bluetooth card nor install the profiles.
So, any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I would perhaps change the question a bit to put emphasis on the fact that you have a problem with getting it to work on Windows, and not a question of theory as to why it doesn't work on Windows compared to Ubuntu. *The short answer could be that the driver functionality isn't available by default, and now you're having some issues getting it to work.*

Comment: Last time I dealt with Windows 7 its bluetooth stack didn't support a2dp. Broadcom made a replacement attack you might try.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth profiles like A2DP are implemented in software, and usually don't require any special functionality in the Bluetooth transceiver.  Which Bluetooth profiles are available can be totally different from one operating system to another (e.g. Windows vs. Linux) since the whole Bluetooth software stack (including the basic OS Bluetooth stack, the drivers for your specific Bluetooth transceiver, and application support for Bluetooth features) is different.